# Why is the html view port meta tag breaking my CSS when I want to make my page responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am working on a small website for uni and have started out by designing the mobile site first. It looked exactly how I wanted it to look on a 320px mobile device. I started using media queries and realized that they weren't working because I forgot to input the view port meta tag in the head of the document. I put this in the head of the doc and it broke my whole design.

Has this ever happened to anyone before? Maybe there is an error somewhere in my code. I spent ages making this because I am new to coding. Thanks in advance to anyone who responds.

Below is a link to the site without the meta tag. The images are how it looks with it.

[The site](https://carla-anne.co.uk/design-for-web/small-business-site-2/index.html)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: include a sandbox for this.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Links to other sites aren't adequate. Consider that "broken" isn't a clear problem description.

Comment: @Najme if you want a sandbox for every question, perhaps there should be somewhere on this site explaining how to do that.

Comment: weird couples!!

Answer (score 0):

Try add this ,

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**More Details**
[Geeks For Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-viewport-meta-tag-for-responsive-web-design/)

Comment: Please provide complete explanations to your answers. You can place links for further reading but it is recommended to put the basic information about how this can help in the answer itself